# Multiple themes or template on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have 7 designs for 7 pages. All the design are different from each other and really has no similarity with each other. Is it possible to apply all those design on a same site as I an familiar with three designs only which are Home(For Home Page) and Page(For All inside Pages) and another is Post same as Page. But I have seven HTML design for seven kind of pages beside home and post. How can I apply that. If not then please give me any suggestion how to do it. I am very new at Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 7 wordpress templates and to apply each template to the page you want.
To make a wordpress template you need to add this to each template page:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Your template name
*/
?>
```

Then you can select which page which template to use when you edit the page.

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress you can apply a different template to each of the pages you create. You can choose the template, in the page editing section, by opening the drop-down menu on the right side of the screen which is called "Page Attributes".